# Portable washer for document metadata

Tags: software-development, portable, privacy, metadata

So I'm doing some work for a smaller company. They wanted a standalone secure client that they can wash all their documents metadata in. Mostly it's PDF and office(doc & docx).

The problem is that it's using Windows PE right now running from RAM (I'm unable to change this). So they want to run some sort of program on this Win10 PE that can clean documents. 
I've searched far and wide online, but haven't really been able to find any program that would let me do that. One way would b to use powershell, but then I somehow gotta get the Microsoft.Office.Interop assembly to install on this PE live boot thing.

Does anyone have any recommendations or anything? I'm running out of ideas over here :(

Comment: By wash their metadata do you mean remove or change?

Comment: @SteveBarnes By wash I mean remove.